# my javascript first method is not working , why?

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops

Can anyone explain what is wrong in 1st section of the code?

```js
// this is not working
let arr = [1, 2, 1, 4, 5, 4, 2, 3];

function except(arr, exclude) {
  for (let key in arr) {
    for (let key1 in exclude) {
      if (arr[key] === exclude[key1]) {
        arr.splice(key, 1)
      }
    }
  }
  console.log(arr)
}
except(arr, [2, 4])
// expecting [1, 1, 5, 3]
// getting [1, 1, 5, 2, 3]
```

If the 2nd value in exclude is present only one time in the arr, then it's working fine

I tried this method and it is working....

```js
let arr = [1, 2, 1, 4, 5, 4, 2, 3];
function except(arr, exclude) {
  let final = [];
  for (let key of arr) {
    if (!exclude.includes(key))
      final.push(key)
  }
  return final;
}
const output = except(arr, [1, 4])
console.log(output)
```

Comment: When you use arr.splice to remove the current element, the next iteration of the for loop will skip the element following the one you removed.

Comment: You are splicing the array as you iterate over, so your index `key` on `arr` no longer means what you think it does.

Comment: so what can replace arr.splice(key, 1)  if I want to keep rest of the code?

Comment: Decrement `key` by 1 when you splice.  `arr.splice(key, 1); key--;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Splice works on position](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice) - you try to splice on the key as position.

Here is a possible fix

```js
let arr = [1, 2, 1, 4, 5, 4, 2, 3];

function except(arr, exclude) {
  exclude.forEach(key1 => {
    let pos = arr.findIndex(item => item === key1);
    while (pos !== -1) {
      arr.splice(pos, 1);
      pos = arr.findIndex(item => item === key1);
    }
  });
  console.log(arr);
}

except(arr, [2, 4]);
```

Why not filter?

```js
let arr = [1, 2, 1, 4, 5, 4, 2, 3];


const except = (arr, exclude) => arr.filter(item => !exclude.includes(item))
const output = except(arr, [1, 4])
console.log(output)
```